# Pass a class property as parameter

Tags: c#, observablecollection

Is it possible to pass a property of a class as parameter, and then update the existing oservablecollection?

i have the following class:

```
public class People
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public string Surname{get; set;}
}
```

and then i have this observable collection:

```
public ObservableCollection<People> people {get; set;)
```

Is there any way to pass one of the people properties as a parameter in a method like this:

```
public void Update(object whichproperty)
{
   var item = people.FirstOrDefault(i => whichproperty == "someone");

       if (item != null)
          {
              whichproperty= "anothersomeone";
          }
}
```

The parameter whichproperty should check if we are dealing with the property name or surname of the People class.

Comment: it is not the same, looking at my code it's visible that i want to update the observable collection